# Is "Featured" the right text for the bounties tab?

Tags: discussion, bounties, user-interface, question-lists

On the Home page and Questions page, we have a tab for questions that currently have bounties. The tab reads "Featured". I've long wondered why we used "Featured" rather than something like... I don't know... "Bountied". I asked some of my coworkers and the response I got was

> Someone typed "Featured" into a text file 10.5 years ago and it stuck, is my guess. ;)

Now, I'm not sure we've had bounties - or at least this tab - since the site first launched but that's being a bit pedantic. There may be a more official answer out there somewhere, but I figured I'd see what your thoughts were about changing it.

To be fair, I'm not sure that "Bounties" or "Bountied" sound particularly great but they do actually say what that tab contains, which "Featured" doesn't. On top of that, we use "Featured on Meta" to indicate questions that moderators or staff have tagged with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag, which don't have a bounty associated with them. Using the term in such different ways could be confusing to users.

The thing is, I'd like the option to use "Featured" for something else that's more similar to how it's used in relation to Featured Meta posts, which is why I'm asking this question.

Here's what the tabs look like on the Home page of Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Question List sorting tabs with the fourth tab circled, which reads "Featured"]

#### Should we change this text to read "Bounties" or "Bountied"? or something else? Or should we leave it the way it is?

If something else, what? Promoted? A few ground rules - well, one: It needs to be the same length as "Featured" or shorter.

Comment: Requesting migration to ELU, or User Experience ;) _(joke aside: this is something I've wondered about too, so I'm glad to see it being asked)_

Comment: I think it should be kept the way it is; the name invites new answers on sites like Stack Overflow.

Comment: @sonic If you're going to answer - answer. I'm not sure how "the name invites new answers".

Comment: 10.5 years ago... hmm, there's a very small number of slots in the wheel of blame (tm)

Comment: From one perspective, you could say 'a person _pays_ with reputation to have their question _featured_ in an exclusive-ish section', in which case the name makes some sense.

Comment: What about *beloved* because they are questions that were loved and therefore got bounties? Also positive in regards to the welcoming project. :)

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... some questions got bountied by the OP because of desperation to get answered... whether it's *beloved* or *urgent*, I don't know...

Comment: @andmyself That is why I proposed "Priority" in my real answer below.

Comment: "Bountified" has a special ring to it, and would serve to keep SE unique in its terms. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I think that it makes sense to name the tab Bounties or Bountied.

I like that as a name because it accurately describes what will be found on that tab.

Comment: SO uses bounties for their tab,  so someone clearly agrees

Comment: I'd say it should be "Bountie**d**" rather than "Bountie**s**" in order to keep the grammar consistent.

Comment: @alex There would be no reason to keep the same grammar between the old tab name and the new tab name. There is no sense of parallelism among the tab names in general anyway; the others aren't all past-tense verbs, so the name of this tab doesn't need to be either.

Comment: @JasonBassford I meant keeping it consistent with the other tabs. The other tabs relating to types of questions are all words that modify the term "questions", e.g. "active questions" and "hot questions". "Bountie**d**" would fit that structure ("bountied questions") whereas "Bountie**s**" is not a word that modifies the term "questions" but is a separate noun.

Comment: @Alex I mispoke. *Bountied* is an adjective, not a past-tense verb. That aside, *Bugs*, *Reqs*, *Week*, and *Month* have nothing to do with the same pattern of grammar. That's what I was talking about. *Active*, *Featured*, and *Hot* are not in their own distinct group.

Comment: @JasonBassford *Bugs* and *Reqs* are unique to this site. The other sites only have *Active*, *Featured*, *Hot*, *Week*, and *Month*. I think we can group these as two categories, where the first three refer to types of questions and the last two refer to time periods.

Comment: One of the other tabs is "Unanswered", so the -ed form matches there.

Answer (score 4):

In a *manner of speaking* - bounties are what you pay for it to get featured. Its an action performed by a user, not a quality of the question.

Bounties feels.. odd in that context. Bountied makes a little more sense, but means nothing unless you get the way we do things already.

The overloading is unfortunate - but you're *not* going to feature posts outside meta (where it has a specific purpose, which incidentally includes sticking it in a side bar). If we think of featured as "Things we would like people to see" or "things we think are neat" it works in these contexts.

Promoted has this nasty twang of the random placement ads places like twitter uses. It does reflect the nature of the questions. It does fit the fact you're 'paying' rep for 'advertising'

I wonder if a compromise might be bringing the featured tab to per-site metas, and letting mods use it for announcement type posts, and putting [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions there (and here). Main meta would have both, cause bounties on meta are a little... odd.

This makes things a lot more consistent, everywhere,and moves the hard work to the "business logic" of the site

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has now been changed according to your recommendations. Good decision by the developers.

Answer (score -4):

At first I thought of the name *Priority* questions but I think this is a bit too extreme. Therefore I suggest to call them ***Highlighted*** questions because that is what a bounty does.

I would advocate against *paid* because then users might think that this site costs money.

Comment: "Highlighted" doesn't describe it very well.