# Separate contexts for "Bounties" on questions page and user profile page

Tags: feature-request, localization, russian-stackoverflow, custom-question-lists

For the purpose of better localization we need to separate contexts (add `REFERSTO` key in Transifex sentence) for "Bounties" word used on [questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) and [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity):

> [image: questions]

> [image: user profile]

In Russian for the first case it would be translated as "Конкурсные" (adjective), for the second as "Конкурсы" (noun).

Note that the above first screenshot is from the Custom Question Lists alpha; users who are not opted in to that will see the word "Featured" instead.

Comment: It's interesting that you would make this suggestion for the Russian when "Bounties" here is the only tab with a noun on the questions page in English. (We had this discussion [back in January](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322629/323179) to see what the tab should be renamed, but it wasn't changed on the home page from "Featured".)

Comment: @Laurel Russian is not English, but some issues are related :) As far as I can recall I had a missunderstanding with that "Featured" tab once, in particular when distinguishing with the red [tag:featured] tag.

Comment: @Laurel On the questions page, it says "Bounties".

Comment: @Sonic Yeah but on the [home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) it says "featured". The question page seems to only have changed because of custom question lists.

Comment: @Laurel Ah, right, only users opted into the CQL alpha see the word "Bounties".